# Путь к файлам базы данных PostgreSQL (Debian)

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда установлена база данных PostgreSQL.
Не могу найти в `/usr/local/pgsql`

Comment: Какая её часть? Исполняемые файлы? Пространства таблиц? Что-то ещё?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `psql` введите команду `show data_directory;`